# Is there any way to format velocity template .vm file?

Tags: format, velocity

I have to put my .vml file in DB table. For that I have to keep this file in a single line.

Is there any way to format the velocity template file (.vm file) ?
Also it is difficult to troubleshoot with vm file when its not formatted.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

jetbrain java IDE Intellig IDEA can be a choice for you